# How do i submit a package into ups to receive a tracking number? (PHP)

Tags: php, xml, soap, ups

before getting into the api i am a little confused to how this all works.
i have an ecommerce site that i am building its not a third party and
i have a dropdown that displays all the shipping types and their prices
so once teh customer selects the shipping they want and checksout how do i
submit the purchase into ups so that ups can provide a tracking number?
how does that all work?

would the ups tracking api have this information? if you know it can you please
explain so that i have a better understanding of how it works.

thanks alot

ps would you know any references oher than the api page to learn how to do this?

Comment: Question available as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26501963/ups-shipping-lable-needed-and-for-that-need-an-tracking-number-for-getting-label

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was recently conneting to ups api and their api is divided into few modules. I was using Shipping API and it works like this:

- collect informations from user
- send request to api with user data
- as an answer you get (among many other things) tracking number and file with shipping label in format you choose in request

If you have any other questions be my guest.

Comment: thanks i got many :p , which document did you read to recieve the shipping number? was it only the shipping api?